# Flash animation in Android device

Tags: android

Can we run a flash animation inserting the .html, .swf and .fla files in the assets folder to run flash animation in Android device?Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flash file requires the Flash Player runtime to...well...run. The ability to run flash files is available to the Android platform in two forms.

1. **As a plugin that renders Flash content in the native Android web browser**(just like your browser on your desktop computer), or by utilizing the **Android UI webView API** and loading an HTML file with an embedded Flash file. In other words, create a webview in your Android application and load it with the remote or local URL of HTML file with the embedded flash content.  Essentially you are putting a stripped down version of the Android browser into your application to render the Flash file.
2. **Adobe AIR for Android**. You could rewrite your Android application into a Flex Mobile Application, if your application relies heavily on Flash, and then run it directly as and AIR application and just us the AIR API's to load it.

Loading a locale resource:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/UI/mylocalhtmlfile.htm");
```