# FLA File Support [android]

Tags: android, flash

1. Android supported files format does not support .fla files, is
    there any way to run multiple .fla files in android.
2. Brower also does not play flash files in android, I could convert .fla
    files to html5 but that's manually process.
3. I'm trying to play many .fla files in sequence in android

Is that possible? Any help appreciated.

Comment: its .FLA file - type of flash file

Comment: how u r using the file in ur app?

Answer (score 0):

A `flash file` requires the `Flash Player` runtime to...well...run. The ability to run flash files is available to the Android platform in two forms. Which are specify [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7472624/1405983).

Comment: yes right but for that i need support of Air app to install..I m trying  to built independent app...if possible can i install flash app in background.I dont wanna ask user to insatall flash from play store. In short i can say i wanna flash app which is independent

Answer (score 0):

You may play your files in Frame tag under HTML file. and call html file to run the Fla file. For play many files you may call another html of your .Fla file from first .Fla file.

I edited this answer.

this is object Tag in HTML

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="main" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
```

It call the main.swf file. and button under main.swf file call the another html file like shelf.html

Comment: ahha..its is so easy na......frd thats not possible in android ....did u tried that if yes then plz give ur intelligent code to me

Comment: I use .swf file to play under Webview. when I click a Button from .swf file then it call the html file. and the html file contains the path of another .swf file. 
I did not know the code of .swf file because that was develop by another department .